# Is this element an algebraic integer?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, integers, minimal-polynomials

Let $\beta = 1 + \frac{\sqrt[3]{5}}{3}$. Is this an algebraic integer?

Now, let $F = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}) = \mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ be the number field generated by $\sqrt[3]{5}$.

I know that $\beta$ is an algebraic integer if and only if its minimal polynomial $f_{\beta}$ is in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Hence, I've tried to find the minimal polynomial of $\beta$, but this gets extremely messy and cumbersome. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Don't work with $1+\frac{\sqrt[3]{5}}{3}$. Work with $\frac{\sqrt[3]{5}}{3}$, which minimal polynomial is very simple to write. If the first were an algebraic integer, since $-1$ is also an integer (root of $x+1$) then so would be their sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that cumbersome.

We have $\beta - 1 = \frac{\sqrt[3]5}3$, which gives us
$$
(\beta - 1)^3 = \frac 5{27}\\
27(\beta - 1)^3 - 5 = 0\\
27\beta^3 - 81\beta^2 + 81\beta - 32 = 0
$$
and we see that the minimal integer polynomial is not monic.